# Load PDF depending on language | Firefox bug?

Tags: html, pdf, firefox

I was trying to load a pdf depending on the currently selected language. If i view the page with firefox it always shows the same file no matter what language is selected. With microsoft edge it works fine. The rest of the page updates and adjusts to the language just fine in firefox tho.

The file is being displayed with this object tag where #{language} is already in server side being substituted with either "de" or "en".

```
<object id="cv_pdfDisplay" type="application/pdf"
  data="resource/pdf/file_#{language}.pdf"
  width="830px" height="800px">
  <a href="resource/pdf/file_#{language}.pdf">download</a>
</object>
```

I checked the generated code in firefox and the path to the file changes just fine. But the displayed pdf is always the same. If i try to access the files directly by entering their address it also shows the same file for both addresses.

Since it only happens in mozilla firefox i am assuming it is a browser based bug? Seems like some issue with the cache to me. Is there some way to make this work on firefox?

Running on firefox 55.0.3 32-bit
Files are called "file_de.pdf" and "file_en.pdf". My locales are "de" and "en".

Answer (score 0):

The problem resulted from a mix of my setup and the cache of firefox. Due to testing i had the same file for german and english version. I replaced the english version later on, once the function was implemented and seemed to work. Firefox had apparently cached the original file and didn't load the new one into the cache. Due to that it kept loading the old one / same one.

After manually clearing the firefox cache, it worked fine.